# Implicit function theorem metric spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability

Are there versions of the implicit function theorem in spaces that lack a natural linear structure, e.g. metric spaces. A quick google search has found me no results.

I am specifically interested in applying such results to the space of probability measures on some Polish space equipped with the $p$-Wasserstein metric.

Comment: My guess is: since the IFT may be viewed as an application of fixed-point theory, and fixed-point theory has been studied in general metric spaces, there should be some version of this possible in your settings.

Comment: @suvrit - I agree with your comment.  It's just that one would need some object in a general metric space  to fulfil the role played by the Frechet derivative in a Banach space

Comment: Have a look at the book "http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783764387211" for doing "gradients" in metric spaces; Wasserstein spaces etc. are a special focus too.

Comment: Thanks for the reference but the link seems to be broken.  Can you give me the name of the book?

Comment: The link above has a spurious quotation mark " -- if you remove it the link shoudl work (name: *Gradient flows in metric spaces* ...)

Comment: Ah the book by Ambrosio et al. Yes this was my first idea - using a notion similar to the metric derivative to derive such a result.  I'll try pursuing it further.  Thanks for the suggestions :)